# Increment integer pointer in a loop in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

My original code to display nodes in a queue in order from lowest to greatest:

```
void display (queue *q) {
node *ptr = q->front;
int i = 0;
int size = q->size;
while (i <= size) {
    while (ptr->id != i) {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    if (i == 0) {
        printf("%d ", ptr->id);
        printf("%d\n", ptr->running);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d ", ptr->id);
    }
    i++;
    ptr = q->front;
}
```

}

Had kept producing Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) errors. I have malloc the two variables being compared and this error has been fixed.

```
void display (queue *q) {
node *ptr = malloc(10);
ptr = q->front;
int *i = NULL;
i = malloc(sizeof(int));
*i = 0;
int size = q->size;
while(*i <= size){
    while (ptr->id != *i) {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    if (*i == 0) {
        printf("%d %d\n", ptr->id, ptr->running);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n", ptr->id, ptr->running, ptr->ready, ptr->blocked);
    }
    i = i + 1 * (sizeof(char));
    ptr = q->front;
}
```

}

However now this doesn't produce the output that I want. I want to increment the i pointer so that it can be the same as my original code.

This has been immensely frustrating, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have memory leak here `node *ptr = malloc(10);`
`ptr = q->front;`

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating a single `int`? And why are you multiplying by `sizeof(char)`, which is 1 by definition?

Comment: @melpomene: That was the method i found to fix the segmentation fault, i multiplied by sizeof(char) as an attempt to add by 1 to the pointer

Comment: Your second approach does not solve the segmentation fault it is just fact the you are not hitting that case.

Comment: @Jason You didn't fix anything, you just added more bugs to the code (which now hide the original bugs).

Comment: Is there any advice to fix the original segmentation fault?

Comment: `i = i + 1 * (sizeof(char));` This is `UB`. Overall your first approach was way better

Comment: @kiranBiradar Yes definitely however it still has segmentation fault, how do I fix it?

Comment: @Jason provided [mcve] and more context we can help you out.

Comment: @Jason what is `ptr->id` supposed to contain?

Comment: There are some open cases, what about q is NULL etc. How is the queue set-up? -> MCVE

Comment: Or you can just add  NULL check `while (ptr->next !=NULL && ptr->id != i)` this is the best we can suggest now.

Comment: I'd suggest editing the question details with 1. struct queue ( I assume you have defined this some where) , 2. enqueue ( or some sort of insert function ) , 3 display keep the display which you have now and 4. main with just the call sequences which eventually calls display that should provide MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your first code listing correctly, there's at least one important thing here you need to think about. You seem to have a linked list here, and you're iterating over that list using `ptr = ptr->next`. This means you need to know when to stop. One common way of setting up a linked list is that the last item in the list has a `next` value of `NULL`. Then process the nodes one at a time, and once you are done with one node, you you check whether the `next` value is `NULL`: if it isn't you can move on that that next node, if it is `NULL` you stop.

Here you're not doing checks like this, so you need another way to ensure that you know when to stop. What you seem to be doing is taking the value of `q->size` and using that to inform you how many items there are in the linked list. So the first thing to think about is how confident you are that that value is correct. For example, if the code building the list puts only two items into the list, bet sets `size` to three, you'll end up falling off the end of the list, and a segmentation fault is not unlikely.

But there's something even more important than that. Even if you're getting the correct number of items in the list from `q->size`, you're comparing your loop variable `i` to `size` like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i <= size) {
  ⋮
}
```

This is going to loop with `i` having the values [ 0, 1, … `size` ], which is actually `size` + 1 times. If you want to loop exactly `size` times, you want a test like `i < size` rather than `i <= size`. This is a common mistake, often called an [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Unfortunately, your second listing complicates things, rather than making them better. Go back to your first one and see if you can fix the things I've mentioned here.